# Which addresses are used in fcp header?

Tags: san, fibrechannel

I have a little question .
The src address and the dst adress are fcid ?
Tnx 
[image: fcp header]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Source/Destination addresses here are 24 bit FC Port addresses which consist of 3 bytes: Domain ID, Area ID and Node ID. Details you can find, for example, here: https://www.storagefreak.net/2014/10/fibre-channel-addressing